# OpenCV-2.4.0,NetBeans7.0.1, Ubuntu11.10,undefined reference to `cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans-7, ubuntu-11.10

I am using OpenCV-2.4.0 with NetBeans 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.  The following call:

```
intLeftTriangleIndexImage=cv::Mat::zeros(fpInput.iRows, fpInput.iColumns, CV_32S);
```

results in

```
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)
```

There appears to be only one library directory for OpenCV-2.4.0, to wit

```
OpenCV-2.4.0/release/lib/
```

and I have linked to all of the libraries therein.  I do not understand why I am getting a link error for what seems like a very basic call.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance in this matter,
Peter.

Comment: Can you post the compiler command.

Comment: The compiler commend exceeded the buffer size.  I had a similar project that worked so I just copied the make file and changed replaced the name of the old project with the name of the new.  I wish NetBeans let one manually copy and paste the library names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function is defined inside `libopencv_core.so`, so make sure you are linking to `opencv_core`.

```
$ nm libopencv_core.so | c++filt | grep zeros
000db520 T cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size_<int>, int)
000db330 T cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Karl Phillip.  I fixed the problem by copying the make file from a project that worked.  But this will be very useful for future reference.